# How do I compare the date from the user with the date in the database? in symfony

Tags: date, doctrine-orm, symfony4

I use symfony 4.when i compare date i can only compare years as below not days or months. if it is in different months and days in the same year, it shows equal to each other. i want to compare with days, month and years.
"p.createdAt" type is datetime

```
    if (!empty($filter['startDate'])) {
        $qb->andWhere($qb->expr()->gte('p.createdAt',':startDate'))
        ->setParameter('startDate',$filter['startDate']);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use code like this:

```
$qb->andWhere('p.createdAt >= :queryDate')
    ->setParameter('queryDate', $queryDate);
```

without problem.